# What is the security impact of deserializing untrusted data in Java?

Tags: java, security, serialization

Is it safe to deserialize untrusted data, provided my code makes no assumptions about the state or class of the deserialized object, or can the mere act of deserializing cause undesired operation?

(Threat model: The attacker may freely modify the serialized data, but that's all he can do)

Comment: If the serialized data contains personal information, or bank information, then absolutely(there is a security risk). This is what encryption is for. It's hard to say this without making any assumptions about the code. In some code bases it would be, while others I presume there wouldn't be. The point of public and private variables is to guarantee that certain states are impossible. You lose this guarantee when de-serializing untrusted data. the question is whether your code has such guarantees, and how important they are

Comment: This question is about the dangers of deserializing, not serializing. I understand the latter, and the communication is indeed encrypted.

Comment: I mention de-serialization. And untrusted sources.

Comment: For starters, if your program's correctness depends on the singleness of singletons (or even something like interned instances), there's a potential risk unless you manage returned objects explicitly.

Comment: @Cruncher: And my question mentions that my code makes no assumptions about the state of the deserialized object.

Comment: @meriton The point is that, that's a malformed requirement. I could create a class such that any de-serialization into it would cause no problems. And I could another one that would cause problems. So knowing nothing about the class, you can not assume that this is safe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deserialization itself can already be unsafe. A serializable class may define a `readObject` method (see also the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#2971)), which is called when an object of this class is going to be deserialized from the stream. The attacker cannot provide this code, but using a crafted input she can *invoke* any such `readObject` method that is on your classpath, with any input.

#### Code injection

It is possible to make a `readObject` implementation that opens the door to arbitrary bytecode injection. Simply read a byte array from the stream and pass it to `ClassLoader.defineClass` and `ClassLoader.resolveClass()` (see the javadoc for [the former](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20int)) and [the later](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#resolveClass(java.lang.Class))). I don't know what the use of such an implementation would be, but it is possible.

#### Memory exhaustion

Writing secure `readObject` methods is hard. Up until [somewhat recently](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u40/jdk/diff/11987e85555f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) the `readObject` method of `HashMap` contained the following lines.

```
int numBuckets = s.readInt();
table = new Entry[numBuckets];
```

This makes it very easy for an attacker to allocate several gigabytes of memory with just a few dozen bytes of serialized data, which will have your system down with an `OutOfMemoryError` in no time.

The [current implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u40/jdk/file/b03bbdef3a88/src/share/classes/java/util/Hashtable.java) of `Hashtable` seems to still be vulnerable to a similar attack; it computes the size of the allocated array based on the number of elements and the load factor, but there is no guard in place against unreasonable values in `loadFactor`, so we can easily request a billion slots be allocated for each element in the table.

#### Excessive CPU load

Fixing the vulnerability in `HashMap` was done as part of changes to address another security issue related to hash-based maps. [CVE-2012-2739](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-2739) describes a denial-of-servic attack based on CPU consumption by creating a `HashMap` with very many colliding keys (i.e. distinct keys with the same hash value). The documented attacks are based on query parameters in URLs or keys in HTTP POST data, but deserialization of a `HashMap` is also vulnerable to this attack.

The [safeguards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes7.html) that were put into `HashMap` to prevent this type of attack are focussed on maps with `String` keys. This is adequate to prevent the HTTP-based attacks, but is easily circumvented with deserialization, e.g. by wrapping each `String` with an `ArrayList` (whose hashCode is also [predictable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode())). Java 8 includes a proposal ([JEP-180](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/features#180)) to further improve the behaviour of `HashMap` in the face of many collisions, which extends the protection to all key types that implements `Comparable`, but  that still allows an attack based on `ArrayList` keys.

The upshot of this is that is possible for the attacker to engineer a byte streams such that the CPU effort it takes to deserialize an object from this stream grows quadratically with the size of the stream.

### Summary

By controlling the input to the deserialization process an attacker can trigger the invocation of any `readObject` deserialization-method. It is theoretically possible for such a method to allow bytecode injection. In practice it is certainly possible to easily exhaust memory or CPU resources this way, resulting in denial-of-service attacks. Auditing your system against such vulnerabilities is very difficult: you have to check *every* implementation of `readObject`, including those in third-party libraries and the runtime library.

Comment: +1 I think the moral of the story here, is that serialized objects are not the right way to accept input.