# java - deserialization of untrusted data workaround

Tags: java, security, serialization, deserialization

Last year we encountered the so-called **java object deserialization vulnerability** (not a java's problem as it looks), which is deserializing an object which might lead to Remote Code Execution (RCE) or Denial of Service (DoS) attacks.

Refer, https://dzone.com/articles/java-serialization-vulnerability-threatens-million for details.

Basically, if the code fails to validate the incoming object, it's vulnerable.

Impact of this attack would be pretty high as described in,
[What is the security impact of deserializing untrusted data in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054460/what-is-the-security-impact-of-deserializing-untrusted-data-in-java/19109839#19109839)

First the attacker used classes from **InvokerTransformer** from **Apache Commons Collections** as a way to build the attack chain.

**Solution 1 : Blacklisting** The classes which have been used to build the gadget chain are not accepted.

But, this is not enough as the attack chain can be constructed in many other ways. Refer,

https://github.com/frohoff/ysoserial/tree/master/src/main/java/ysoserial/payloads

**Solution 2 : Whitelisting** By overriding the ObjectStream with a "SecureObjectStream", which validates for classes that are actually expected by the application.

Again, this doesn't negate the attacks completely. There is a RCE using jre7u21 and a Denial of Service attack using HashSets.

**Solution 3 : Turn off deserialization** The best one yet.

### Question

In cases where deserialization cannot be neglected, is there a better way to validate and stop the bad data before it explodes other than black & white lists?

Comment: Some nice guidelines: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27492407

Comment: Perhaps use of a transport format such as json, xml or protocol buffer is another alternative?

Comment: Solution 4: Only accept data from trusted sources - verifyable e.g. by a RSA/ECC signature.

Comment: Update your commons collection jar to version 3.2.2.

Comment: @GhostCat Yeah. SER04-J, SER12-J, SER13-J comes within the context and i think most of the information has already been included in the post.

https://tersesystems.com/2015/11/08/closing-the-open-door-of-java-object-serialization/ can be referred to know why SecurityManager and some other data validations aren't enough.

Comment: @Taylor, In case where "serialization/deserialization cannot be neglected".

The options you gave are alternatives for serialization.

Comment: @Robert Yes, signatures can be used. Limits to the scenario where our clients are known and pre-defined, if i am not wrong.

But there might be use-cases where the endpoint is open to the world.

Comment: @Sudershan In such a case only solution 3 is secure. The Java serialization format is mobile code and you should never expose an code execution interface to the world. Use a data-only format instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to think of the risk and who gets the serialized data. An internal admin interface with only 3 super-admins able to access it, does not require the same attention as a public website. In the first case, you might even not fix it and settle with the compensating controls.
Second, you need to prioritize your suggestions: turning off serialization is the best option as it eliminates the risk. White listing specific classes is the second best and should be chosen if serialization cannot be turned off, but blacklisting is not recommended as you won't think of all of the options and it would be bypassed. I wouldn't consider blacklisting as a valid solution.
Another possible solution, depending on the use-case, is encryption and\or signing (HMAC) of the serialized data. In .NET you have the Viewstate that can be used for deserialization attacks to take over it, but if it is signed or encrypted in a proper manner, you cannot modify it, so this is another valid solution. So you can choose one of these 3 (excluding blacklisting).