# Serialization can lead to security problems. How to overcome them? What approach to be followed?

Tags: java

From many Java Docs, blogs and tutorials, I have read that, "**Java Object Serialization might break the Encapsulation leading to security Issue**". What is that Security Issue and How to overcome them in Java? Does Java has any other methodology to overcome Serialize approach?

Note: Read many articles in StackOverFlow which doesnot mention the Security Issue clearly.

EDIT: It is quite different to [What is the security impact of deserializing untrusted data in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054460/what-is-the-security-impact-of-deserializing-untrusted-data-in-java)
No suggestions or solutions to overcome the problem and very minor info on how it affects the Application. The question might be quite broad so good to know majority of problems faced by developer s.

Comment: if you really need complete information, I suggest "Effective Java" chapter "Serialization". I hope this will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the security impact of deserializing untrusted data in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054460/what-is-the-security-impact-of-deserializing-untrusted-data-in-java)

Comment: @Amin - Link for "Effective Java" please.

Comment: you can find it with a easy search. link: https://github.com/edwin-ngai/book/blob/master/%5BJAVA%5D%5BEffective%20Java%203rd%20Edition%5D.pdf

Comment: I think this question is too broad, as it asks too many things at once. The part that asks what the dangers are is a duplicate. And "how do I serialize and deserialize data without using Java's built in serialization API?" is pretty broad and opinion-based as well: there are lots of ways to solve that problem.

Comment: @DanielPryden Will make edits and remove the duplicate ones.