# How to determine the boundary when reading with ois.readObject()

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

If the sender uses `ois.writeObject` to continuously send two objects of the same class to the receiver, and the receiver uses `oos.readObject` to read, is it possible for the receiver to treat the two data packets as one? And when the class to be serialized is very large, how does the receiver know when the reception is complete?

There is a way to point out that `Object` can be used as boundary markers, but I don't know if it is correct

```
//sender
out.writeObject(obj1);
out.writeObject(new Object()); 


out.writeObject(obj1);
out.writeObject(new Object()); 


//receiver
Object obj;
while ((obj = in.readObject()) != null) {
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        // Boundary identification, process the next object
    } else {
        // process the received object
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "treat the two packets as one"? Two objects are two objects, not one ... and why do you think you need to identify "boundaries"? And by the way, using Java Serialization for remote communication may introduce [security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054460/what-is-the-security-impact-of-deserializing-untrusted-data-in-java).

Comment: @meriton I think the OP has a persistent connection open and needs to treat every two objects as part of a single "message". Essentially, they're asking how to write their own application-level communication protocol, specifically how to delimit separate messages.

Comment: @OP If you're going to use Java serialization, why not just create a class that represents a single message and contains all the data of that message? That way the reader only has to read objects as they come in. The "wrapper" object itself would be the delimiter. But, as pointed out, Java serialization has its issues. Consider using a different format mechanism.

Comment: Should also point out that `obj instanceof Object` is always going to be true, as all classes ultimately inherit from `Object`.

Comment: @Slaw, yes, this is an experiment for one of my computer network courses. I need to write a chat program. I defined a `Message` class that contains all types of data, but I am thinking about whether it is necessary to design an application layer protocol to allow the receiver to distinguish the boundaries of the message.

Comment: The `ObjectInputStream` class already knows where an object begins and ends. If you write a `Message` to the stream, then when you call `readObject()` you'll get that `Message` object back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I am thinking about whether it is necessary to design an application layer protocol to allow the receiver to distinguish the boundaries of the message

Java Serialization does that for you. If Java Serialization didn't do this, it would be impossible to read more than one `Object` from a `ObjectInputStream`, since the boundary between the objects would be unspecified. If you're curious how Java Serialization does this, the [Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/serialization/), in particular the [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/serialization/protocol.html) section, should prove instructive (very briefly: variable length data is prefixed with its length).

That said, using Java Serialization to interpret untrusted data is likely to result in [serious security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054460/what-is-the-security-impact-of-deserializing-untrusted-data-in-java). Most networked software is better served with more robust serialization formats, such as JSON or XML. There are open source libraries for both of these.

Alternatively, you could reinvent the wheel by using a naked `DataOutputStream` / `DataInputStream`. For comparatively simple messages, this shouldn't be too onerous.